# How to use RequireJS to load and run modules only once

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs

I have common module on my app that retrieves data from remote server and have `get` methods to export the retrieved data to other modules.

Lets assume that this module's name is `MyData`:

```
define([], function(){

    return function(opts) {
        var data = null;

        // go get data with ajax
        var getData = function(){
            $.ajax("getData").done(function(response){
                data = response;
            });
        };

        getData();

        // return public api
        if (arguments.length !== 0) {
            var method = arguments[0];
            switch (method) {
                case "get": return data;
            }
        };

    };

});
```

The problem is when I define other modules that use `MyData`, everytime it would create a new instance of `MyData`, causing it to retrieve the data from the server each time.

I could use web storage (or other global variable) to store the returned data, but it seems like a bad solution.

Is there any way to force RequireJS to create only once instance?

**P.S:**
In my project I user KnockoutJS, and the `data` variable is an ko.observable, so maybe knockout has a solution for my situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RequireJS already loads each module once. You just need to restructure your code a bit:

```
// myModule.js
define(function() {
    // The dataFetch Promise will be initialized when this module
    // is loaded for the first time.
    var dataFetch = $.ajax("getData");

    return {
        getData: function () {
            // Return the Promise interface and let callers use the
            // .done, .fail etc. methods on it
            return dataFetch;
        }
    };
});
```

Usage:

```
define([ "myModule" ], function (myModule) {
    myModule.getData().done(function (data) {
        // use the data
    });
});
```

By using the Promise interface returned by `$.ajax`, you can ensure asynch access to data that's fetched only once.

BTW, perhaps the pattern that you're trying to implement is a Model.